# Removing part of a URL in htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I haven't really worked within htacess before and the last time I tired something it messed up badly, so I am hoping to get so direction:

How do I remove part of a URL for a mass amount of links and redirect

I need to redirect this:

```
/2015/08/blog-post/?from=/page/3/&in_cat=0&page_num=3
```

to this:

```
/2015/08/blog-post/
```

I need to delete all of this URL: `?from=/page/3/&in_cat=0&page_num=3`

for this site, its works still if you change out the page numbers so I need to clear it all together

I poke around the forums and found this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?from=(?:/(.*))?$ /$1$2 [NC,R=301,L]
```

but could not get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can just use this Jennifer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(\d{4}/\d{2}/[^/]+/?)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

But you'll really need to update the blog software to stop generating them that way if you want to get the full benefit.

The key part is the question mark, towards the end of the last line, which removes the query string. The second line just checks that there is one.

The format it matches for the blog posts is:

- 4 numbers
- slash
- 2 numbers
- slash
- one or more non-slash characters
- optional slash